# Two conventric circles

Tags: geometry

**Problem:** Two concentric circles have a common midpoint with radius 1 and 4 respectively. These two form a circular ring with thickness $4-1=3$ (Basically a torus seen from above in 2D). Find the radius of a third concentric circle with the same midpoint, such that it divides the area of this circular ring in the ratio 1:2, counted from the midpoint.

**Attempt:** The area of the circular ring is given by $$A_c=4^2\pi-1^2\pi = 15\pi.$$

The fact that this aea should be divided into the ratio of 1:2 means that the area closest to the midpoint should be $10\pi$ and the other area closest to the periphery should be $5\pi$. So we need to find a third concentric circle with radius $1<r<4$ such that it's area $r^2\pi$ causes this ratio.

The area of the circle ring formed between the small circle and the new ring is $$A_1=r^2\pi-\pi=(r^2-1)\pi.$$

The area of the circle ring formed between the new ring and the outer ring is $$A_2=A_c-r^2\pi = 15\pi -r^2\pi = (15-r^2)\pi$$

So dividing $A_1/A_2$ and equating to $1/2$ gives us $$\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{(r^2-1)\pi}{(15-r^2)\pi} = \frac{r^2-1}{15-r^2}=\frac{1}{2} \ \Longleftrightarrow \ r_{1,2}=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         \sqrt{\frac{17}{3}}\\
        -\sqrt{\frac{17}{3}}\end{array} \right.$$
Discarding $r_2$ we have that the radius of the new circle should be $$r = \sqrt{\frac{17}{3}} \approx 2.3805$$ which seems quite reasonable, but is incorrect. Anyone care to advice where I treaded obliquely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your third equation, you wrote that $A_2=A_c-r^2\pi$ when it should be $A_2 = A_c-A_1$, which equals to $(16-r^2)\pi$. Hence, $$\frac{r^2-1}{16-r^2}=\frac{1}{2}\implies r=\sqrt{6}$$

Comment: Ofcourse! Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Glad to have helped. :) :)

Comment: By the way, is there another method of solving this problem? Using calculus?